# Suppose there is userId connected to a column. How to retrieve rows contains the users who links to all unique values in that column

Tags: r

Simple example

I have different users(a,b,c) links to another column one

[image]

suppose I know the unique value in column, which is managable, I want to extract rows that  users connect to all unique values in column one, for this picture I will pick all rows contains user a. But in real data, there are million users and more variables.I want to know who connects all unique values in column one and retrieve all rows contains this user. Can any one help me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally you should post a reproducible example instead of pictures. I created one for you this time.

We can first find out the `unique` values in the dataframe and then `filter` those groups which have `all` the `unique` values.

```
unique_value <- unique(df$value)

library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  filter(all(unique_value %in% value))

# group value
#  <fct> <dbl>
#1 a         1
#2 a         2
#3 a         3
#4 a         4
```

---

Using base R, we can use `ave` and `subset` the dataframe.

```
subset(df, as.logical(ave(value, group, FUN = function(x) all(unique_value %in% x))))
```

**data**

```
df <- data.frame(group = c("a", "b", "c", "a", "a", "a", "c"), 
                 value = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2))
```

Comment: Which is also `?setequal` - `df %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  filter(setequal(value,unique_value))
`

Comment: @thelatemail did not use this function before. Could be good alternative to `all`. Thanks for sharing. :)